# Why do all type_traits Classes have to be called using 'typename' and '::type' Prefix/Suffix?

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, type-traits, typename

This is kind of an odd question although it is pretty obvious:

Why do all templates in `<type_traits>` have to be called with `typenname` and `::type` prefix/suffix?

One reason would be, of course, that there was no templated typedef like the C++0x `using` thingy, that allows the following:

```
template<typename T>
using remove_ref = typename std::remove_reference<T>::type;

remove_ref<int&> foo = 4;
```

So this question is less about, why it currently is that way, but more about **whether this behaviour is going to be simplified in future C++ standards?**.

Similar improvement could come with traits like `std::is_pointer<T>::value` - I can already see templated constants at the horizon of C++14/17 that would allow uses like `std::is_pointer<T>`.

**Note:** To my knowledge, this simplification is not subject of any of the published items concerning the upcoming C++ standards. In this case, there is no real yes/no answer to this question and this thread could act as a pro/con list whether this is likely to be changed in any new versions of C++.

**EDIT:**

Thanks to @Drew_Dormann and @erenon that have correctly pointed out that there already have been `_t` versions added to all type trait templates that exactly do that.

However, it is still open, whether there are any signs that value traits like `std::is_pointer` will be part of a similar simplification besides the `std::is_pointer<T>()`-Version?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> However, it is still open, whether there are any signs that value
>   traits like `std::is_pointer` will be part of a similar simplification
>   besides the `std::is_pointer<T>()`-Version?

Yes. The first [library fundamentals TS](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n4335.html), currently in DTS ballot, adds numerous `_v` variable templates. For example:

```
template <class T> constexpr bool is_pointer_v
  = is_pointer<T>::value;
```

Like everything added in a TS, it's in the `std::experimental` namespace. They have been implemented in the trunk version of libstdc++ and libc++.

Answer (score 5):

In c++14, there is [`remove_reference_t`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/remove_reference), which is exactly what you are looking for.

Comment: Strange, how I haven't come to this?!
Well, then it is to be answered, if this change will also be applied to ::value templates

Comment: @hdv Thanks for the parenthese version. I also updated the question to be more specific.

Comment: @JakobRiedle I was wrong, variable templates are part of C++14. I must have misremembered. Still, there's no `std::is_pointer_v<T>`. It would not save on typing over `std::is_pointer<T>()` anyway though.

Comment: @hvd Yep. So this seems like the c++ comittee spammed std:: with the "wrong" templates :-D

Comment: @T.C. But it's not in any standard and doesn't appear to be getting in one. N4081 proposed adding it, N4270 is the revised version that eventually got accepted, but N4270 doesn't contain any mention of it.

Comment: @hvd N4270 is a "patch" against the working draft. N4335 is the post-Urbana working draft that's been (will soon be?) sent out for DTS ballot.

Comment: @T.C. Ah! Thanks. It seems wrong, then, for N4270 to show "Revises: N4081". But what's done is done.

Comment: @hvd You're right, but the names are all longer, so the new names are not as good, as they would have been, if the original names would have not been used. that's what I mean